# chrome javascript debugger: how to enter value and see it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a html which has an input box. I want to use the keyboard to enter some text in the input box and in the debugger I want to see input box's value.

but when I run the debugger with "ctrl+r" , the web page become inactive, so I can't enter.

how can I do that?

Comment: enter the text then go into the debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug, you need to use browser `Console` window.

To activate console window in chrome, here are few options

1. Press **F12**
2. Right click on your page and choose `Inspect` option
3. Press `ctrl` + `shift` + `i`

You will get a develper window, Here choose the console tab.

[image]

Once you are here you can write your Javscript/ Jquery (if library is loaded) and debug the values.

[image]

**To debug Functions or event handlers**
Add this keyword `debugger;` in any line from where you want to debug, Then open up the developer window and then do the activity which will trigger the function execution, The `Sources` window will stop right at the line where it hits `debugger;` and from there you can use `F10`,`F11` etc keys to debug.

Look for these options

[image]

Comment: I am doing debug with your instructions. but could not do it after I input something in html.

Answer (score 0):

ctrl + r is for refresh the page , not the debugger.

for debug you need to do one from two options:

**1) insert in your code "debbuger;" in the line that you want to stop there**

**2) put a break point using the chrome developer tools**

attach for you link that will help you with all that :

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3